# how to hide over x chars in a string

Tags: php, javascript, css

it's very common to substring an item description if it's too long,

But how could show it back?

i was thinking

```
if string length is > x
   insert after position x a <span classs="more">   //probably i'd do this through php
   insert at the end of the string </span> 
   hide ".more"  //css & javascript to hide and show
```

and then you can simply use a technique like: [toogle parent's element with parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513062/toogle-parents-element-with-parent)

Do you see any alternative for this?

Comment: Seems like a fine solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without JavaScript assuming you don't care about support for old browsers that don't understand the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class (e.g., IE6 only does `:hover` for `<a>` elements).

Something like this:

```
<style>
.full { display: none; }
.shortened:hover .full { display: inline; }
</style>

<span class="shortened">This is some text that <span class="full">has been cropped.</span></span>
```

In case it's not obvious what this is doing, the first CSS selector hides all elements with the class "full". The second selector shows elements with the class of "full" if they are a child of an element with class "shortened" that also has the mouse over it.

If there are other elements after the outside span they'll temporarily move over to make room while the extra text is visible - a simple way to avoid this is as follows (tweak to suite your taste):

```
.shortened { position: relative; }
.full { display: none; position: absolute;}
.shortened:hover .full { display: inline; z-index: 100; background-color: white;}
```

Comment: but you omited the x position detect :)

Comment: Ha, well, I assumed you'd do that in PHP like you said in your question. I'd definitely do that part server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have a php script file that returns the full text and then use ajax to fetch the rest of the description and replace the shortened text.

Comment: sure but that will allways cause a waiting for request.. no?

Comment: It can depending on how many requests are being made. In my experience AJAX calls are pretty cheap. You can temporary store the data using jquery.Data so you dont need to fetch it each time the user clicks on show/hide. I would only suggest this if you have a long description and dont want to return the full description when the user may not what to see the full description. The option you mentioned previously are perfectly valid but you asked if there were any alternatives which this is just an alternative. It may not be the right one for your project but it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS in modern browsers: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` will cut the text and show `…` in the end of box. You must specify width / height, so the text would overflow rather than make the container bigger. (Supported in IE7+, FF4+, modern Webkits and Opera)

Edit: noticed, you need exact per character cut. Then, to use my suggestion,e you will need mono-space font (and, possibly, em specified box width).

Comment: It sounds retarded, but you can only apply text-overflow:ellipsis to texts with `word-wrap: nowrap`, which means _only to single-line texts_ .. luckily, there is a dirty hack - `<pre>` has `word-wrap: nowrap` by default, so you can make a multi-line ellipsis on it, BUT you will obviously need to insert line-breaks before (with PHP, JS or manualy) ..

Comment: Buuufff, well, thanks for the info but i don't think it's the solution i want, then...