# How to make a JavaScript menu more functional

Tags: javascript, dynamic, menu

I wonder simply which way is the best practice to make this menu dynamic. I don't want to make a function for each Element.
Should I push them into an Array then loop through them?

```
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="button1"></div>
        <div id="button2"></div>
        <div id="button3"></div>
        <div id="button4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="navHover">
        <div id="hoverButton1"></div>
        <div id="hoverButton2"></div>
        <div id="hoverButton3"></div>
        <div id="hoverButton4"></div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

            var buttonOne = document.getElementById('button1');
            var buttonOneHover = document.getElementById('hoverButton1');
            
            buttonOne.addEventListener('mouseover', buttonOneBlock, false);
            buttonOne.addEventListener('mouseout', buttonOneNone, false);
            
            buttonOneHover.addEventListener('mouseover', buttonOneBlock, false);
            buttonOneHover.addEventListener('mouseout', buttonOneNone, false);

        function buttonOneBlock() {
            var buttonOneHover = document.getElementById('hoverButton1');
            buttonOneHover.style.display = 'block';
        }

        function buttonOneNone() {
            var buttonOneHover = document.getElementById('hoverButton1');
            buttonOneHover.style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>


#nav {
width: 960px;
height: 20px;
background-color: white;
margin: auto;
}
#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4 {
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}
#navHover {
width: 960px;
height: 20px;
background-color: white;
margin: auto;
}
#hoverButton1, #hoverButton2, #hoverButton3, #hoverButton4 {
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
background-color: orange;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
display: none;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic'? Try to explain what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: what do you mean make it dynamic?

Comment: So that I don't need to create functions for every single element.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to take your existing code that only handles button1/hoverButton1 and apply it to buttons 2-4 without repeating the code three times? Note that (assuming you don't care about IE6) you can do pretty much the same thing with _no_ JavaScript, i.e., all in CSS - you could adapt the approach I suggest [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513909/how-to-hide-over-x-chars-in-a-string/7514211#7514211).

Comment: No I don't care about IE's DOM. Im on course there I learn JavaScript.  So it needs to be in JavaScript and yes, I don't want to repeat the code. Excuse me for the unclear explanation.

Comment: What is exactly the expected effect, with a little bit more css and a jquery usage, you can do it very properly, describe exactly what you want for all buttonHover, what kind of menu are you trying to make?

Comment: can't use jQuery when im now learning pure JavaScript. What I want is when I hover over "button1" the "hoverButton1" will come up. So far I've accomplished a function. I just don't wanna repeat that function on every single element.

Comment: Ok then Daniel solution is the good one.

Comment: Yes, I will make to try solve it with something similar to his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a straightforward generalization of that:

```
function setupButton(i) {
  var button = document.getElementById('button' + i);
  var buttonHover = document.getElementById('hoverButton' + i);

  button.addEventListener('mouseover', buttonBlock, false);
  button.addEventListener('mouseout', buttonNone, false);

  buttonHover.addEventListener('mouseover', buttonBlock, false);
  buttonHover.addEventListener('mouseout', buttonNone, false);

  function buttonBlock() {
    buttonHover.style.display = 'block';
  }

  function buttonNone() {
    buttonHover.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
  setupButton(i)
}
```

Comment: I've tried many different ways now. And I can't get this to work.